# I am trying to convert a varchar into a date, but I keep getting this error below

Tags: informatica-powercenter

I am trying to convert `varchar` into a date in Informatica, but I keep getting this error below

> invalid string for converting to Date
>   ... t:TO_DATE(u:'2020-02-13T11:13:58.4861917-06:00',u:'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')

Could you please help me with the syntax?

Answer (score 0):

Above syntax will not work because the value in the data filed is not exactly a date. You have *T* character in between and the seconds are in decimals. You have to substring the value and convert it to date. Below is the syntax,

```
TO_DATE(substr(date_column, 0,10),'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

[image]